# recovering the cell address of a vlookup statement

Tags: excel, vba

is there a way to get `address_of(vlookup(.....))` ??

where `address_of = "A25"` (or something in that format) ??

Comment: you're spamming us with your excel formulae

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [`MATCH()`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/match-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a) rather than Lookup. The formula below assumes you've got a lookup table in A1:A12.

It looks for the value "60" and turns the returned row index into a textual range address (e.g. "$A$6").

```
=ADDRESS(MATCH(60,A1:A12,0),1)
```

The third parameter in `MATCH()` makes this an exact match.

Comment: missing a "0" in the formula

Answer (score 17):

```
=ADDRESS(MATCH(60,A1:A12,0),1)
```

Missed out the `,0` making it approximate and not an exact match. This is not good for drop downs combo menus; if two things can be the same, then you need an exact match or it picks up the last one.

Comment: This really need to be marked as the answer or someone needs to come back and edit the accepted answer